# How to express in TypeScript the type of a Record minus some of its key in a generic manner?

Tags: typescript

I have a function that filters out some keys from a `Record` and I want the type safety to prevent me from accessing filtered out keys.

What I got to express that is:

```
// Filters out the result of OnlySelected to remove never from filtered out keys
type OmitNever<T> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends never ? never : K]: T[K] }

// Only keeps the keys that are in the type V
type OnlySelected<T extends object, V> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: K extends V ? T[K] : never
}
```

Which works great for simple use cases:

```
const a: A = {
    a: 1,
    b: "2",
    c: "3",
    d: "4",
    e: "5",
}
type MyType = OmitNever<OnlySelected<A, "a" | "b">>;
// type MyType = {
//    a: number;
//    b: string;
//}
```

But now if I try to use theses types in a generic function I have to means to convert the type of the keys that I want to keep to an union type. So I have to provide the type by hand and it's sad to have to repeat the keys to keep twice just to be type safe:

```
const filterRecord = <T extends Record<any, any>, TO_KEEP>(record: T, keys: Array<keyof T>) => {
    return Object.keys(record)
        .reduce((acc, it) => {
            if (keys.includes(it)) {
                acc[it as keyof OmitNever<OnlySelected<T, TO_KEEP>>] = record[it];
            }
            return acc;
        }, {} as OmitNever<OnlySelected<T, TO_KEEP>>)
}

const res = filterRecord<A, "d" | "e">(a, ["d", "e"]);
console.log(res.d)
console.log(res.e)
console.log(res.a)
```

Anyone knows the solution or a better design?

See the playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=37&ssc=19&pln=24&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2AOQgNwgJwDwBUB8UAvFAN5QDaA0lAgHZQDWEIA9gGZS5QCGAzl2oBdKBAAewCHQAmAuuixQA-FHkZMUAFxQqQ7bmFQAvgCgToSLDoAbEAGUI1iAGNJ0vKIlTZUVgCMAKxdgABooADVCElITKDjKGnomFg4uIQBaJW0acUkZAXDlQV0tVQVME1NzcGgAQWIyWPiebToAVzg-LABuJri-bT5gTHoAc174qGdB4bGJ+OkZkbpxvtElucqzZ1Y6Id5teui1lqgARhC1gagAIgAmG8vJ6duAZke1xduAFg-JiG0NwArB9TBZoABZEC4GoNeBIVDqbAwGz2RzBCDuWphG48G5QAA+tz8N3w+F6Jh2e2AUHYCGskkwACUXKxMNIGh5ct4BCyduzsDw6CAwkKQPgwrgYAB9KgAUTlAAV8AAKTCs9n6MLMEB8Q6YTA8EDYHWpAgASmIhBik3VwDamAYMECwQAdDq+GqNdJzWtJq71dI2s4ICqVTxnM4wkhLURrX7JvEEJwVR7XfRnNY2tIIJ6Y5abYmi5MI84KEheAJTZx4ShysjUQ4nK5MXhJTL5UqySISOr+dJy8AhPNi-FTKPbRB7Y7eJGR4mjGFSEZK7BEHWkSjbE2Me5cO3ZQrlfhfVUqft1QISHSGVg+WysTjpPiiTcIKTw2EKDdnzj30JzV6c9WCcV1rFYUYvT4V0fUpXY+BAiAwIgqDXQgX1gNA8DIMvV0eHNIA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `filterRecord`'s `TO_KEEP` as `extends keyof T`, then use `TO_KEEP[]` as the parameter type. TypeScript will infer correctly then (but keep reading):

```typescript
const filterRecord = <T extends Record<any, any>, TO_KEEP extends keyof T>(
    record: T,
    keys: TO_KEEP[]
) => {
    return Object.keys(record).reduce((acc, it) => {
        if ((keys as readonly string[]).includes(it)) {
            acc[it as keyof OmitNever<OnlySelected<T, TO_KEEP>>] = record[it];
        }
        return acc;
    }, {} as OmitNever<OnlySelected<T, TO_KEEP>>);
};
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2AOQgNwgJwDwBUB8UAvFAN5QDaA0lAgHZQDWEIA9gGZS5QCGAzl2oBdKBAAewCHQAmAuuixQA-FHkZMUAFxQqQ7bmFQAvgG4AUGdCRYdADYgAyhFsQAxpOl5REqbKisAIwArN2AAGigANUISUjMoBMoaeiYWDi4hAFolbRpxSRkBSOVBXS1VBUxzUwsraABBYjJ4xJ5tOgBXOACsc0SoAO0+YEx6AHM+xNchkfHJhOkZ0boJloSIJbmzGrNXVjph3m1G2LWjqABGMLPBqAAiACY76-7p+4BmZ7PF+4AWL-6G3uAFYvjU6lAALIgXDgaAkeBIVDqbAwOyOZyhCCeeoRO48O5QAA+9wCd3w+HMu32h3YCFskkwACU3KxMNIml58r4BCy9uzsDw6CAIkKQPgIrgYAB9KgAUTlAAVvAU-Mw2JwCAAKM6YVns-QvRLqvj6GXypUUIRmACUxEIcX6euAHUwDBgwVCADoTVq9fzpDavXrpB1XBAtVqeK5XBEkHaiA6zv0EJxIybeAI9TxpPt7FBhssxlag-RXLYOtIIHwtfG7Y7+o2EtHXBQkJnUhrYIgUJVUeinC53Ni8JLzQrFRSRCR-WzpG3gEJ5o2jMnEs7XQwW8ujBFSEYO4jeyi0fZB1jPLgx7KJxSbdUqXsDsAoHqBCQ6QysHy51GIhQ7mkZ57ggO4hHvakDlYFwvVsVgxj9asvUDcwnz4aCIFg+DEL4L0IAgtCMKwhC3y9Hh7yAA)

Note that I did have to add a broadening type assertion within the implementation there (`keys as readonly string[]`) in order to use `includes`, but that's harmless.

---

Side note: Unless you're using it for some other purpose, you can avoid needing `OmitNever` by changing your definition of `OnlySelected` slightly (but keep reading):

```typescript
type OnlySelected<T extends object, V> = {
    [K in keyof T as K extends V ? K : never]-?: T[K];
    // −−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−^^^^
};
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdgGxAZQgiBjYEAmAeAFSggA9s4cBnKAewCMArTYAGigDUA+KAXigG8AUFBFQA2gGkoASzhQA1hBA0AZlCIBDalNLkqHKAH4oUgFxQ4EAG4QATgF0AtIfMFJ9gNzDRAeh9RAJCIg4JCAPXCIyKjo6JCAyMEAXy9BUEgoAEFeAW8RDXM4AFcAWzo7L1EoOnNKYFtZAHMK0QwausbmkRw2+rgm3OIejqSUjBo4Wqh8zOyhSumARhYB6qgAIgAmNeXK1vWAZm2B7vWAFiPKiHM1gFYj5NTwaABZEAIn7PgkVHQsXDwMmw1ho1lAAD7rOhrTijcaTFTSBDYWwAJUwNFsOGyhGIZAgFGoaLGmLwGjgIDYZJAnDYBBgAH0JABRJkABVxemoimUagInAAFANbOjMa4dqJuZRXAzmWyxPZBABKXjcOaiYXAQq2OQwRjMAB0kv5wuJOEV+uFOEKGAg-P5GgwGDY0mAyp4qoGlWkajtkqm1GFGhw4yQUFqvQa8vNsgwCEKOAglH5LsVyrVlQzU0dYhd-oUSlUsEQKDQzH+BFpMpZrM49myJoxOBzwE8ntEiTbIg1WrkDownSgiTY-ESea+Jd+2HwFfUVbZnEVXgegjGE2AUGF1D4CKRdiJjftbDEaxw23WEDW9kXK7hNHQ+oQNAaxsT+rNXlXlDvEAfT5flH1CBr0-b9f2fTd9Q0RcgA)

---

**But**, `OnlySelected` seems like it's doing the same thing the built-in `Required` and [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) do, so you could just use them(or define `OnlySelected` in terms of `Required` and `Pick`). ([Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oEMBcUB2ArgLYBGEATgNxoYm4DOw5AlngObUZQDGDTrHGugAmfFu04YIYgdQC+1FNwD2eRllxxEqLjigBGADRCodKACIATOeNdeFgMw2ToiwBZnXaRYCszhSigkFAAsiAAKuDQiABKEACOBMzkEMIAPAAKzNwA1mkwhhaY5lAAPhYk5gB8VYoqasBQAGbMADbAFHEq5MIIUGnhUBAAHh14wvRQXco9aZh4IIXzIFWF4QDyAPoA0gCiuxlDoxDjkzkQIMpNUOFVABQmKd2u4bYY5yD0uBs7+xkA2gBdFAASgQVWQjwgwAI5DwUHWJAAVhBuMAAHQfeh3J4zYQg9EpYQEbgQO53TDcbiFZjAMHwCE6LgYZjXclYrCTFKYYSqVogKCMcRsIEE1jcVoEYQQbG0kFgpnM5mU7j-WmcqAfK5TBJJImZbJ5V43LZ7A41QF9XE9NXAQGSJVyExcFIwuFYKkOqByQpIOQauKJZKpA25AZrU1-Gog+R1VTqFKTRAtdqdVF4imFf7mYQ2CwQcyAmNKePKVoQdGtZRsHEy9H46j1ehlitVmuJ9EQYtNluV6u1+jozAxoA)) *(Thanks to [caTS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18244921/cats) for [pointing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74401728/how-to-express-in-typescript-the-type-of-a-record-minus-some-of-its-key-in-a-gen/74401867?noredirect=1#comment131349666_74401867) the `Required` part, I'd missed the flag mod and just mentioned `Pick` before.)*

Comment: Okay, thanks for the very detailed answer! This does solves all of my problems :D Small question though? If you have time ^^ How does `TO_KEEP extends keyof T` translates to a union type?

Comment: @IoannisNoukakis - Glad that helped! That's just the nature of [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#handbook-content), which *"...produces a string or numeric literal union of [an object type's] keys..."*

Comment: Crowder Oh okay! Thanks for your time and replies ^^ I'm off reading the TS docs once more!

Comment: Isn't `OnlySelected` already built-in to TypeScript as `Required<Pick<..., ...>>`?

Comment: @caTS - I flagged up half of that (`Pick`) at the end of the answer. Good point about `Required`, though, I missed out the flag mod. :-)

Comment: Simpler version: https://tsplay.dev/N9nk9m